# How to get audio devices and names

Tags: python, audio, pyqt, pyqt4, device

I am trying to get the audio devices names from using PyQt4 framework in Python.

The code is as follows:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtMultimedia

temp_list=()
x=()

for i in range(5):
    temp_list=QtMultimedia.QAudioDeviceInfo.availableDevices(QtMultimedia.QAudio.AudioInput)
    x=QtMultimedia.QAudioDeviceInfo.deviceName
    print temp_list
    print x
```

yet somehow I can't get the device names. Not too sure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 4):

It seems from your example code that you don't have much experience of using Python. I would advise you to work through some tutorials before proceeding any further. The [Beginners Guide](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide) on the Python wiki is a good place to start.

I would also advise you to make full use of Python's interactive mode when trying to work out how the Qt APIs work. With the use of `print`, you can answer basic questions very quickly and easily. Here's an example session:

```
Python 3.3.3 (v3.3.3:c3896275c0f6, Nov 18 2013, 21:18:40) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PyQt4 import QtMultimedia
>>> devices = QtMultimedia.QAudioDeviceInfo.availableDevices(QtMultimedia.QAudio.AudioInput)
>>> print(devices)
[<PyQt4.QtMultimedia.QAudioDeviceInfo object at 0x00CC5C30>, <PyQt4.QtMultimedia.QAudioDeviceInfo object at 0x00CC5C70>]
>>> for device in devices:
...     print(device.deviceName())
...
Intel(r) Integrated Audio
default
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another way of doing it also, sounddevice lib is nice and easy to use !

```
py -m pip install sounddevice
```

- 

```
import sounddevice as sd

def query():
    a = sd.query_devices()
    print(a)

query()
```